# django rest выдает 404 страницу вместо информации о модели

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Хочу получить информацию об объекте модели при помощи django rest

В urls.py у меня

```
url(r'^backend/api/load/detail/<int:pk>', views.LoadDetail.as_view())
```

В views.py:

```
class LoadDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Load.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = LoadSerialiser
```

При переходе по ссылке /backend/api/load/detail/4/ получаю ошибку 404

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `/` в конце ссылки в urls.py. `^backend/api/load/detail/<int:pk>/`

Comment: Пробовал и со /, и без, и не регуляркой, а строкой 'backend/api/load/<int:pk>/' - все равно 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил на `path('backend/api/load/<int:pk>/', views.LoadDetail.as_view())` и заработало. Было бы здорово узнать, почему так и как обрабатывать запросы с pk при помощи регулярок